# How to ensure good, different initial NumPy MT19937 states?

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed, mt19937

### Introduction - legacy NumPy

The [legacy NumPy code](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState) of initializing MT19937 instances (same as on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Initialization)) ensured that different seed values lead to different initial states (or at least if a single int is provided). Let's check the first 3 numbers in the prng's state:

```py
np.random.seed(3)
np.random.get_state()[1][:3]
# gives array([         3, 1142332464, 3889748055], dtype=uint32)

np.random.seed(7)
np.random.get_state()[1][:3]
array([         7, 4097098180, 3572822661, 1142383841], dtype=uint32)
# gives array([         7, 4097098180, 3572822661], dtype=uint32)
```

However, this method is criticized for 2 reasons:

- seed size is limited by the underlying type, uint32
- similar seeds may result in similar random numbers

The former can be solved if one can provide a sequence of int (which is indeed implemented, but how?), but the latter is harder to address. The implementation of the legacy code has been written keeping this property in mind [^1].

### Introduction - new NumPy random

In the new implementation, the *seed* value provided is hashed first, then used to feed the initial state of the MT19937. This hashing ensures that

- the similarity of the seed values doesn't matter, 2 similar seed values produce different initial state with the same probability as non-similar seed values. Previously we have seen that, for adjacent seed values, the first state variable (out of 600+) is similar. Whereas in the new implementation, not a single similar value can be found (with high chance) except for the [first one for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528594/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-fixed-value-as-the-first-state-in-numpy-mt199):

  ```py
  prng = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(3))
  prng.bit_generator.state["state"]["key"][:3]
  # gives array([2147483648, 2902887791,  607385081], dtype=uint32)

  prng = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(7))
  prng.bit_generator.state["state"]["key"][:3]
  # gives array([2147483648, 3939563265, 4185785210], dtype=uint32)
  ```
- Two different seed values (ints of any length) may result in a similar initial state with a probability of $2^{-128}$ (by default).

If the problem of similar seeds has been already solved by Matsumoto et el., [^1], then there was no need to use a hash function, which introduces the state collision problem.

### Question

Given the new implementation in NumPy, is there a good practice that ensures the different initial states of the MT19937 instances and passes quality requirements when it comes to similar seed values? I am looking for an initialization method that consumes at least 64 bits.

How about modifying the `generate_state` output of the SeedSequence class: if two ints are given, replace the first 2 states ([maybe except the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528594/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-fixed-value-as-the-first-state-in-numpy-mt199)) with the given seed values themselves:

```py
class secure_SeedSequence(np.random.SeedSequence):
    def __init__(self, seed1: np.uint32, seed2: np.uint32):
        self.seed1 = seed1
        self.seed2 = seed2

    def generate_state(self, n_words, dtype):
        ss = np.random.SeedSequence([self.seed1, self.seed2])
        states = ss.generate_state(n_words, dtype)
        states[1] = self.seed1
        states[2] = self.seed2
        return states


ss_a = secure_SeedSequence(3, 1)
prng_a = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(ss_a))
# gives [2147483648          3          1  354512857 3507208499 1943065218]

ss_b = secure_SeedSequence(3, 2)
prng_b = np.random.Generator(np.random.MT19937(ss_b))
# gives [2147483648          3          2 2744275888 1746192816 3474647608]
```

Here `secure_SeedSequence` consumes 2*32=64 bits, `prng_a` and `prng_b` are in different states, and except for the first 3 state variables, all the state variables are not alike. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Algorithmic_detail), the first 2 numbers may have some correlation with the 2 first state-variables, but after generating 624 random numbers, the next internal state won't reflect the initial seeds anymore. To avoid this problem, the code can be improved by skipping the first 2 random numbers.

### Workaround

[One can claim](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/parallel.html) that the chances that two MT19937 instances will have the same state after providing different entropy for their SeedSequence is arbitrary low, by default, it is $2^{-128}$. But I am looking for a solution that ensures 100% probability that the initial states are different, not only with
$1-2^{-32\cdot N}$ probability.

Moreover, my concern with this calculation is that although the chance of getting garbage streams are low, once we have them, they produce garbage output forever, therefore, if a stream of length $M$ is generated, and $N$ streams/prngs are used, then by selecting $M$ pieces of numbers from this $M \times N$ 2D array, the chances that a number is garbage, tends to 1.

#### Why I asked it here?

- this is strongly related to a given implementation in NumPy
- the chances that I get an answer is the highest here
- I think this is a common issue and I hope others have investigated this topic deeply already

[^1]: Common Defects in Initialization of Pseudorandom Number Generators, MAKOTO MATSUMOTO et al., around equation 30.